# Using two WriteStreams in same spark structured streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a scenario where I would like to save the same streaming dataframe to **two different streaming sinks**.

I have created a streaming dataframe which I need to send to both Kafka topic and delta lake.

I thought of using forEachBatch, but looks like it doesn't support multiple STREAMING SINKS.

Also, I tried using spark session.awaitAnyTermination() with multiple write streams. But the second stream is not getting processed !

Is there a way through which we can achieve this ?!

This is my code:

1. I am reading from Kafka stream and creating a single streaming dataframe.

```scala
val df = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") 
  .option("subscribe", "ingestionTopic1")
  .load() 

df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").as[(String, String)]
```

2. writing the above dataframe to a Kafka topic

```scala
val ds1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9082")
  .option("topic", "outputTopic1")
  .start()
```

3. writing the same streaming dataframe to delta lake

```scala
val ds2 = df.format("delta")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/test/delta/events/_checkpoints/etlflow") 
  .start("/test/delta/events") 

ds1.awaitTermination 
ds2.awaitTermination
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247360/how-to-write-two-streaming-dfs-into-two-different-tables-in-mysql-in-spark-stur/64247709?r=SearchResults&s=1|23.2551#64247709) worked for me, maybe it also solves your question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it Mike. I looked at that code snippet and there we are using two different streaming data frames.  In my case I am using a single streaming dataframe coming from Kafka. And if I use that dataframe to start one WriteStream() operation then the offset gets consumed and has been moved to LATEST and the second writeStream() operation is not consuming it, since it has been consumed by first one.

Comment: Hi @mike - Thank you so much for the edit. I tried using different checkpoint location for each of the writeStreams() and also added awaitTermination() after starting both the queries. But still I could only see the data getting written to only one sink and not to the other.

Comment: Also i have looked the offsets for each sinks, only one of the sinks offset is getting progressed and the other sink's offset remains the same and is not progressing.

Comment: Did you add `writeStream` to the second query?

Comment: Yes i have added it. What I see in the logs is, when the first writeStream() gets started it consumes the offset and processes the data and moves the offset to LATEST. Since its the same streaming DF, when the second writeStream() starts - its still on the LATEST offset and not processing any data (Because Consumer group for readStream Kafka is same - since its single streaming DF)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to follow to use one input stream for multiple output streams:

- You need to make sure to have two different checkpointLocations in the two output streams.
- Furthermore, you need to ensure to have the writeStream call also on your second output query.
- Overall, it is important to start both of the queries before waiting for the termination of both queries. (You are already doing this)

Comment: The checkpoint location hint her eis useful since (at least to me) it's an unintuitive cause of the multiple streaming queries issues I was facing